# ISERROR on whole sheet not working?

Tags: excel

The following formula always returns 'OK' for me:

```
IF(ISERROR('CheckedSheet'!1:65536), "NOT OK", "OK")
```

...while in reality there are multiple issues in the sheet CheckedSheet. Refreshing the whole workbook or just this sheet does not help. Strangely enough, refreshing the formula itself (F2+F9), does change the result to 'NOT OK'. I'm working in Excel 2003, any ideas?

Comment: I tested this in Excel 2010. ISERROR(Sheet1!A1:D10) returns TRUE (I do have an error in that range) if I enter that function in Sheet1. If I enter it in another sheet, it returns FALSE.
It only happens if there are blank cells in that A1:D10 range though... Weird

Comment: it matters where you put the formula and where the error is - try different combinations and you will get different results - it **does** need "array entry" but also another function OR - like this `=IF(OR(ISERROR(Checkedsheet!1:65536)), "NOT OK", "OK")`

Comment: When I do run it, Excel "Runs out of resources". An array formula on 16,777,216 cells is not a good idea. Also, I don't get the OR() here, mind explaining?

Comment: Yes I agree it's not a good idea to run on whole sheet. `ISERROR(range)` returns an "array" of TRUE/FALSE values, those are doing nothing on their own - OR applied to such a range will return TRUE if any of those are true, so then the IF works to identify whether there's an error or not - needs array entry

Comment: Without OR you actually get an array of values returned by the formula, so if A1 has an error but A2:A5 doesn't, then when you use `=IF(ISERROR(A1:A5),"Not OK","OK")` the "test" returns an "array" like `={TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE}` and the IF function returns this: `{"Not OK";"OK";"OK";"OK";"OK"}` - when placed in a single cell you may see "Not OK" or "OK" depending on the cell in which the formula is placed, put it in B1 and you get "Not OK", put it in B2 and you get "OK"

Comment: Well I need to check the whole sheet, I could select the range of used cells, but that keeps growing.

Comment: @pnuts - yes you are right - can't use whole columns in 2003 for array formulas (I'm testing in Excel 2007 which doesn't have that limitation) - you can use COUNTIF, though - which errors do you expect?

Comment: I expect especially #N/A errors, but still I would like to check for all

Comment: So basically, I need to use another function (OR, COUNTIF, ...) and the formula only works depending on where it is placed in the sheet. Phew. Nasty.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula needs another function like OR (and in Excel 2003 you can't use whole columns so you need to restrict that) , i.e.

`=IF(OR(ISERROR(Checkedsheet!1:65535)), "NOT OK", "OK")`

you need to enter with the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> so that curly braces appear around the formula in the formula bar (and yes you also need double quotes)

For a non-array version you could use COUNTIF but normally you can only look for specific errors, e.g. for `#N/A` errors only

`=IF(COUNTIF(Checkedsheet!1:65536,"#N/A"), "NOT OK", "OK")`

Comment: No, this is not the issue. You don't need an array formula for that function. See my above comment.
Plus if you do enter it as an array formula, you'll run out of resources quickly.

Comment: Actually it won't work at all without another function, I altered my answer

Comment: This answer is not entirely correct, as using the OR function and/or the array formula doesn't seem to work for me. However, I've opted to go with the COUNTIF and just checked on "#N/A". Not ideal because other errors might still flow through, but at least I have a working check, so thanks for the workaround.

Comment: ...and I take it back. This method is extremely slow for me. :s Still looking for a global fast solution.

Answer (score 0):

Bit odd that, I had a bit of a play and replaced the single quotes around NOT OK and OK with double quotes and that seemed to sort things out ...

Comment: For the formula to work consistently you still need to "array enter" it - are you doing that? See my answer

Comment: and you also need to alter the formula a little, see my revised answer

Comment: Sorry, should have been double quotes from the beginning, corrected now.